# Specify a color for ellipsis (CharacterEllipsis value of the TextTrimming property)

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a hyperlink that could be trimmed:

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
    <Hyperlink 
        NavigateUri="{Binding Uri}" 
        RequestNavigate="OnRequestNavigate" 
        TextDecorations="None"
        <Run Text="{Binding SomeText, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

But the color of the ellipsis (three dots) is different from the hyperlink. Is it possible to specify the same color for the ellipsis as a hyperlink has itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to set the foreground on the TextBlock to #2169CC.